# Am I a 'repeat ESTA visitor' in US?

Tags: passports, esta

I have been to the US before 10 years ago with ESTA.
And I'm preparing to visit the US again with a new passport and new ESTA.
(The passport that I used before had been expired)

To simplify the US entry procedures, i'd like to use APC(automated passport control). It says that 'repeat ESTA visitor' can use APC and the first visitor to the US isn't available to use APC.

Am I same with the first visitor? or 'repeat ESTA visitor' that can use APC?

Comment: AFAIK, APC rules are very dependant on individual airport

Comment: Related (but old): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67841/am-i-a-repeat-traveler-in-terms-of-esta/97894#97894

Comment: A  'repeat ESTA visitor' is someone who's Biometrics (Face and Fingerprints) have allready been taken by an Immigration Officer on their first visit with a ESTA.

Answer (score 4):

APC has mostly been phased out - it's currently [only available at 7 airports](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc) (and one seaport), most of which are smaller airports with relatively low levels of international traffic.

If you do happen to be entering the US at one of these 8 points of entry, then [as per this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67841/am-i-a-repeat-traveler-in-terms-of-esta) you will be able to use APC with an ESTA as long as you've entered the US at least once since 2008.

Comment: For those who are curious (like I was):  the APC kiosks are being phased out because there's a desire to use facial recognition technology more broadly for arriving travelers, and the APC kiosks don't actually have this technology.  See [this October 2022 HYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/05/travel/customs-kiosks-facial-recognition.html) for details (or [this archive.ph link.](https://archive.ph/HC7L9))